# Lossless image rotate with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I've been working on a system to rotate an uploaded image.  The algorithm works as follows:

```
 1) User uploads a jpeg.  It gets saved as a PNG
 2) Link to the temp png is returned to the user.
 3) The user can click 90left,90right, or type in N degrees to rotate
 4) The png is opened using 

   $image = imagecreatefrompng("./fileHERE");

 5) The png is rotated using

   $imageRotated = imagerotate($image,$degrees,0);

 6) The png is saved and the link returned to the user.
 7) If the user wishes to rotate more go back to step 3 operating on the newly
    saved temporary PNG, 
    else the changes are commited and the final image is saved as a jpeg.
```

This works perfectly fine when rotating 90degrees left and right.  The user can rotate infinity many times without any loss in quality.  The issue is that when the user tries to rotate 20 degrees (or some other non multiple of 90).  When rotating 20 degrees the image is rotated slightly and a black box forms to fill the areas that need to be filled.  Since the image (with the black box) is saved as a png the next rotate of 20 degrees rotates the image (with the black box) another 20 degrees and forms another black box to take up the slack.  Long story short if you do this to 360 degrees you will have a large black box around a very small remaining image.  Even if you zoom in and crop out the black box there is a noticeable loss in quality.

Any way I can avoid the black box? (The server does not have imagick installed)

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25303

Comment: No, there is not. The image has to have square corners because that's how scalar imaging works, and you have to fill it in with something. If you rotate 20 degrees, then you decide you actually want to rotate 40 degrees, you have to start from the base image again, otherwise the image will inevitably decay over subsequent operations. There is literally nothing you can do about this.

Comment: @hakre - I am operating on PNGs, not JPEGs for this reason

Comment: @DaveRnadom - Thanks.  Make an answer and Ill give you upvotes and credit.  Why does rotating 90 degrees result in no black box or loss?

Comment: @user974896: I don't understand your reasoning because there is no lossless rotation with PNG. With JPEG there at least would under certain circumstances - at least technically (not in GD so far).

Comment: Are you trying to squeeze the rotated image into the original image dimensions?  Sounds like you might not be expanding the new image size to fit the rotated original.

Comment: mbeckish, I am simply doing what I stated in my original post.  Opening the file with imagecreatefrompng, using imagerotate on the $image returned from that, then saving the result of imagerotate as a new png

Comment: hakre.  There is no lossless rotate in jpeg either.  Each time the image is saved it will get worse and worse.  By using PNG I at least avoid that. (im doing crops as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always store the source file unmodified and when you rotate, rotate the number of degrees using the original source file. so 20 degress + 20 degress, means rotate the source 40 degrees.

1. User uploads a JPEG.
2. The user can click "90 left", "90 right", or type in *N* degrees to rotate.
3. The png is opened using

   ```
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("./source.jpg");
   ```
4. The png is rotated...

   ```
   // If this is the first time, there is no rotation data, set it up
   if(!isset($_SESSION["degrees"])) $_SESSION["degrees"] = 0;

   // Apply the new rotation
   $_SESSION["degrees"] += $degrees;

   // Rotate the image
   $rotated = imagerotate($image, $_SESSION["degrees"], 0);

   // Save the image, DO NOT MODIFY THE SOURCE FILE!
   imagejpeg($rotated, "./last.jpg");

   // Output the image
   header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
   imagejpeg($rotated);
   ```
5. If the user wishes to rotate more go back to step 3, otherwise the last.jpg is taken as final and the `$_SESSION["degrees"]` parameter is destroyed.